# How to have the sidebar stretch automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have, what I estimate, to be a simple problem.  I have a side bar on my page with its own unique color and I would like it to grow and shrink based on the text in the main content area so that it stretches from the nav bar to the footer.  I tried setting a height on it but that just forces the whole content area to have tons of white space at the bottom.  I would like for the height of the sidebar to be dictated by the amount of content in the main area.

Here is the CSS for the sidebar (if I need to post more code please let me know):

```
.LeftSidebar
{
float: left;
background-color: #1b619c;
color: White;
width: 175px;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
clear:both;
}
```

I am still trying to learn so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing the width and check

Comment: width should be in % otherwise it can lead to variation in different Resolution/Browsers. Please post some sample HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a css column.  There are a couple of options you could go with a css wrapper that sets the three column layout or two column layout.  I would refer you to the following website:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

Or if you are using CSS3 markup then you could also use the display:table and display:table-cell markup to set your columns.  Please refer to this site:

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

```
div#ContentWrapper { display: table; }
div#LeftSidebar { display: table-cell; }
div#MainContent { display: table-cell; }
```

I am showing ID's because the only time you should be using a class is when there are multiple references to that class on the same page.

However it's going to be a bit more complicated than just modifying the css for the sidebar column.

Answer (score 0):

You may set `height:100%` or adjust height in depend of display (screen, monitor) size thru jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function updateView()
    {   
         var obj = $(".LeftSidebar");
         var sc_size = $(window).height()

         var obj_height = sc_size - 90 //90 is example of footer os smthg else height

         $(".LeftSidebar").css({'height': obj_height});
    }
</script>
```

Do `updateView()` on `<body onload="updateView()">`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a DIV element as your sidebar , with a fixed width, it will stretch automatically vertical depending on the size of you content.

and let me put the money where my mouth is : http://jsfiddle.net/alexpeta/NkHY5/

Comment: My whole sidebar is wrapped in a div, still it only extends down as far as the text in the sidebar, not as far as the main content.

Comment: then as far as i can tell, in your case, you need to calculate your height with jquery : $(window).height()